# Send data from multiple html forms to external api via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I've multiple forms on my web page, and I want to send the data from a html form to my own customized api after clicking on 'Submit' button given on the form.

All the forms are like this:

```
<form align="center" class="nav nav-list" id="myForm" method="POST" action="#" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
<p>
    <input id="field_email"
    type="email"
    placeholder="Enter email address"
    name="eml1" required>
</p>
<p> 
    <input id="field_pwd1"
    title="Password must contain at least 4 characters, including UPPER/lowercase and numbers." 
    type="password" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}" 
    placeholder="Enter password"
    name="pwd1" required>
</p>
<div class="pricing-footer">
    <input class="btn-submit-modal" type="submit" value="Register">
    <input class="btn-modal" type="button" value="Close">
</div>
```

After filling the form when I click on 'Submit' button I am calling checkForm() method written in Javascript.

```
function checkForm(form)
{
    // Here I'm accepting the email, password and productKey from the Html form, from which the submit button was clicked.
    var email = form.eml1.value;
    var password = form.pwd1.value;
    var productKey = form.productid.value;

    // Here I want to pass the entered email address, productKey and password to the API mentioned in 'url'.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '*link where I want to send password, email, productkey*'
        datatype:'application/json',
        crossDomain: true,
        data: {
            email: email,
            password: password,
            productKey: productKey
        },
        timeout: 600000,
        error: function (request, error) {
        alert("in error");
        },
        success: function (response) {
            alert("in success");

            if(response==-1)
                alert('Already registered with this email address for this product.');
            if(response==1)
                alert('You are successfully registered to this application, your activation link has been sent out to your email address.');
            if(response==-2)
                alert('Email sending failed.');     
        }
        }); 
    return true;
}
</script>
```

The problem that I'm facing is, the ajax code is not working. The parameters are successfully catched in checkForm() function but for some reasons the Ajax part is failing.
    Can anyone give a solution. In case this is not working, can anyone tell me any other way I can achieve my goals.

Comment: You need to determine exactly what stage of the AJAX request is failing. First job is to check the console for errors. Then have a look at the network requests being sent to see their response codes.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you're calling the jQuery library before your javascript code?

Comment: what error do you get when it fails?

Comment: Is this a cross domain AJAX request?

Comment: If it's a cross domain ajax request, you might need to use a proxy...

Comment: Yes, I'm calling latest jQuery library with a CDN.
Yes, I'm using proxy. 
I get " alert("in error");" and when I try to print the error I see [Object][Object].
Yes, this is a cross domain AJAX request.

Comment: Use console.log instead of alert to print the error object.

Comment: @cakan nothing is being printed using that. Not even this 'console.log ( 'was here' ); is working.
I'm I doing something wrong?

Comment: @overlord It's not printing anything on the screen. You should open console window in your browser in order to see console log.

Comment: Yes I know, I pressed F12 and checked in the Console tag for the output where nothing was printed.